# Weblogic resets JSESSIONID cookie with every request

Tags: spring, cookies, gwt, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am currently maintaining quite big Java webapp and I need to make it work also on Weblogic server 12.2.1.3.0 . The app works correctly on JBoss 7, Wildfly 13 and Websphere.

I am able to deploy the app to Weblogic, start it (without any errors) and login.
The app creates 3 JSESSIONID cookies for 3 pahts ( '/' , '/myApp' , '/myApp/home' ). However the **JSESSIONID cookie for Path '/' changes with every request to the server**. When I go through the network calls in chrome devTools, every call has different cookie value and this breaks my app's session related functionality.

Interesting is that if I remove the cookie with path '/myApp/home', this behavior stops (the cookie with path '/' stops reseting). The same behavior was observed on Chrome and Firefox.

The app is using Spring security 3.2.10 and GWT 2.6.1.

I have tried to go through the spring filter-chains, if I do not find some session invalidation, but without any success (as mentioned, it works correctly on other app servers). Any suggestion welcome

Comment: you may have a configuration issue. If you have only one web-app deployed in your server, WebLogic should/will create only on JSESSIONID cookie for all paths in the application. Can you post your web.xml and weblogic.xml files ?

Comment: @Jaroslav Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @NaiveCoder Unfortunately not - for some reason the problem did not appear on the customer's server and we are using Wildfly pro our production, so it was not "necessary" to solve now (might bite us in a** later).

Comment: In my case, the issue was -  cookie was set as 'secure' in the weblogic.xml and that requires https for browser to send cookies back.

Comment: @NaiveCoder thanks for the comment, I will for sure have look this way when I have to deal with this again. Maybe you can post it as a answer? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the current behavior of WebLogic server is to validate only the first JSESSIONID cookie in the cookie header! Try to set the following java option 
`-Dweblogic.http.tryAllCookies=true`.

Comment: The issue you are talking about is when there are several JSESSIONID cookies in ONE request. More, this issue is corrected in 12.2.1.3